# Podcast stops playing

Tags: ios, podcasts, podcasts.app

A podcast I'm listening has issues in the last few episodes, possibly since the iOS 13 update but I'm not sure.

At some point in the podcast the playing stops. In the "progress view" at the bottom of the app the podcast logo and times disappear and it says "Not Playing". Looks like the app can't decode a specific part of the compressed audio. You can skip the bad part.

Podcast author says he had a few people telling him about the issue, but he didn't change anything in his production process. Is this a know bug in iOS 13? Were there changes in the file formats supported by the Podcasts app?

Comment: Does it happen to every podcast or just ones from this author?  Podcast formats haven't changed in years so I'm thinking this author or the content provider is making a mistake.

Comment: It's only this one, and only the last 3 episodes. Don't know if it's caused by something in the last episodes or iOS 13.

Comment: It's not iOS13.  If it was it would be happening to every podcast as almost all of them use the same set of file formats for years.